# Solutions to the under-damped Harmonic Oscillator equation ??

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, mathematical-physics

For the damped harmonic oscillator equation
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{c}{m}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{k}{m}x=0$$
we get that the general solution is
$$x(t)=Ae^{-\gamma t}e^{i\omega_d t}+Be^{-\gamma t}e^{-i\omega_d t}$$
where $\gamma = \frac{c}{2m}$  and $ \omega_d=\sqrt{\omega^2-\gamma ^2}$. Using Euler's equation, we can expand this as follows:
$$Ae^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\omega _dt)+i\sin(\omega_d t))+Be^{-\gamma t}(\cos(\omega _dt)-i\sin(\omega_d t))$$
$$\Rightarrow e^{-\gamma t}(A+B)\cos(\omega_d t) +e^{-\gamma t}(Ai-Bi)\sin(\omega_d t)$$
But now we are dealing with a physical problem so we only examine the real part which is $e^{-\gamma t}(A+B)\cos(\omega_d t)$. But this does not have any phase difference. Yet textbooks always make the claim that the real part of the solution is
$$e^{-\gamma t}(C)\cos(\omega_d t+\phi)$$
where $\phi$ is some arbitrary initial phase. But where does that initial phase come from if the real part of the solution does not have a phase change in it? I understand that $A$ and $B$ themselves need not be real however I do not understand how this fact could ever lead to a non zero initial phase in the real part of the solution.

This issue has bothered me for quite some time now so any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: You simply forgot that, when dealing with complex solutions, the coefficients $A$ and $B$ (which depend on the initial conditions)  are not necessarily real.

Comment: @Bernard I know that they can be complex but I still don't fully understand how this leads to a solution with a  real  part of the form $e^{-\gamma t}(C)\cos(\omega_d t+\phi)$.

Comment: The reat part can be a linear combination of $\cos$ and  $\sin$, and such a linear combination can be written as a single $\cos$ (or $\sin$ as well) of the same argument, plus a phase.

Answer (score 2):

Your split into real and imaginary parts is flawed for generic complex coefficients *A* and *B*. In general, you may parameterize them as
$$
A=a e^{i\theta+i\phi}, \qquad B=b e^{i\theta-i\phi},
$$
for real  *a,b,θ,φ*. It is evident that  *θ* is superfluous, as its corresponding phase factors out of the linear equation, and thus *x*.

So only *φ* is meaningful,
and it joins up with the dynamical phase $\omega_d t$, providing a new origin for it. *Then*, with real *a,b*, the amended real-imaginary split you attempted  would be sound, and the conventional result would follow for real *C=a+b*.